# How to create gapless ringtone?

Tags: ringtone

I've some usic I want to create ringtone from. When using ringdroid, I always have a gap between two plays of my ringtone. So, is there a way to create gapless looping ringtones ?

Comment: Can you not use PC in this case? Audacity is a good software.

Comment: @Firelord I would prefer not, since I use to tinker with ringtones when I only have my phone at hand